# Find all solutions to $x^3+(x+1)^3+ \dots + (x+15)^3=y^3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all pairs of integers $(x, y)$ such that 
>   $$x^3+(x+1)^3+ \dots + (x+15)^3=y^3$$

What I have tried so far:

The coefficient of $x^3$ is $16$ in the left hand side. It is not useful then to trying bound LHS between, for example, $(ax+b)^3$ and $(ax+c)^3$ and then say that $ax+b<y<ax+c$.

I also tried to use modulo a prime. But it seems unlikely to bound variables this way.

EDIT : Though, it can be factored as $(2x+15)(x^2+15x+120)=(y/2)^3$. LSH factors are almost co-prime and we can say that $x^2+15x+120=3z^3$ or $x^2+15x+120=5z^3$. These are still too difficult to solve!

Any ideas?

Comment: First choose $$x+x+15=2y$$

Comment: I think I can't understand this! Is that a variable change? How did you express $x$ and $y$ in terms of each other?

Comment: The sum $1^3+\cdots+x^3$ is a square, i.e. $(x(x+1)/2)^2$. Does that help?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie I'm not sure how to utilize that!

Comment: You can factorize as in @JaideepKhare's answer.

Comment: One solution is $x=-7$, $y=8$.

Comment: @YuxiaoXie Its $s^3$ and leaves you with a Mordell like equation, not Pell.

Comment: @Ghartal Thanks for correcting. Sorry for the mistake...

Comment: Where do this problem come from? As a Thue equation it should have a finite number of  solutions. I found $x=-7;\;y=8$ and IMHO it's the only one after searching millions of numbers :)

Comment: What's about  $x=−8, y=−8$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a complete solution, but I hope it gives you an approach. (It's too long for a comment)

Since we have $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^3=\left(\frac { n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$

You can write 
\begin{align}
x^3+(x+1)^3+ \dots + (x+15)^3
&=\sum_{r=1}^{x+15} r^3-\sum_{r=1}^{x-1} r^3
\\
&=\left(\frac { (x+15)(x+16)}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac { x(x-1)}{2}\right)^2\\
&=\left[\left(\frac { (x+15)(x+16)}{2}\right)-\left(\frac { x(x-1)}{2}\right)\right]\left[\left(\frac { (x+15)(x+16)}{2}\right)+\left(\frac { x(x-1)}{2}\right)\right]\\
\end{align}

Simplifying this, we get $$(x^2+15x+120)(2x+15)=\left(\frac y2 \right)^3$$

Comment: In fact, this is the easily deduced simplified problem and concerns binary cubic forms which are well known to be very difficult. In particular, making $2x+15=\pm1$, one finds by chance  the other factor equal to 64 then the solutions $(x,y)=(-7,8), (-8,-8)$; similarly making $2x+15=z^3$ one can find integer solutions for this last equation but the corresponding  other factor does not work. All this is just trials and errors  without "true" mathematics.

Comment: @Piquito If this is easy mathematics, please convince me. At least that there are a finite number of cases to check...

Comment: And also, a product can be a cube without each number being a cube. For exemple, for $x=1$ $(x^2+15x+273)(2x+15)=17^3$. So your assumption $2x+15=z^3$ depends on the number $120$ instead of $273$. I don't see why.

Comment: @ama:1)This change of the problem is just the use of the difference of two squares (knowing the formula giving $\left(\frac { n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$).                  2) Nobody has said that necessarily $2x+15$ must be a cube.

Comment: The factorisation is not the problem. What follows in your comment is the problem. Our life is to short to check out all  the values of $2x+15$.

Comment: You win. Good by.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for $(x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ for which 
$$ \sum_{i= 0}^{15} (x+i)^3 = y^3, \tag{0}$$
that is, 
$$ \sum_{i= 0}^{15} \left( x^3 + 3 i x^2 + 3i^2 x + i^3 \right) = y^3, $$
that is,
$$ 16 x^3 + 3 \frac{15 (15+1)}{2} x^2 + 3 \frac{15 (15+1)(2 \times 15 + 1)}{6} + \left( \frac{15 (15+1)}{2} \right)^2 = y^3, $$
that is, 
$$ 16 x^3 + 360 x^2 + 3720 x + 14400 = y^3, $$
which can be written as 
$$ 8 (2x^3  +  45 x^2 + 465 x + 1800)  = y^3  $$
Can you get anywhere from here?

Comment: It begins here! What to do next?

Comment: You could have factorized directly...

Comment: After factorizing still there is trouble!